# Using Linq to access an objects properties within another object

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get a value from an object within an another object. My problem is I can't access any values from within the subobject, i always get the value of the object type itself.

Code where i'm accessing the object

```
var test = scheduledTask.Fields.Select(x => x.FieldValue);
```

This brings back in the results view

```
[0] 10111
[1] {ObjectType.Extension}
```

I need to access the [1] element which contains the following properties (amongst others), and i need to access the DisplayName

```
{
DisplayName: "MainMenu",
CategoryId: -1,
Id: 433
}
```

ScheduledTask is

```
{
Fields: {Fields.Field[2]},
LastModifiedDate:null,
{Fields.Field[2]}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some details on your scheduledTask ? what objects / fields it has and how its set up.

Comment: You might be able to use `OfType<T>` to filter by the desired type and cast to that type.  `scheduledTask.Fields.Select(x => x.FieldValue).OfType<ObjectType.Extension>().Select(e => e.DisplayName);`

Comment: added some details, it's basically just a large object i get from another method.

Comment: @chris It would be more helpful if you pasted the definition of whatever type `scheduledTask` is, the runtime/debugger values aren't very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You don't need LINQ to access a specific index of an array.

```
string name = (scheduledTask.Fields[1].FieldValue as ObjectType.Extension)?.DisplayName;
```

Since the array contains values of different types I assume that we have an array of `object`. Therefore we must cast to the expected type to be able to access specific fields or properties.

In case the value is null or the type does not match `as` will yield `null`. The null-conditional operators `?.` performs a member or element access operation only if an operand is non-null and otherwise return `null`.

If you don't know the index of the required value, you can query with

```
string name = (scheduledTask.Fields
    .Select(x => x.FieldValue)
    .OfType<ObjectType.Extension>()
    .FirstOrDefault()
)?.DisplayName;
```

If you are sure the required value is there and not null, you can drop the `?`.

Comment: So i can't seem to access .DisplayName, i only have options to access the FieldValue which just gives me the object and not specific properties.

Comment: Okay, I corrected my answer. It is hard to infer the correct code without seeing how the types involved are declared.

Comment: So i'm having to do the following

?scheduledTask.Fields[1].FieldValue.ToEnumerable().Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("DisplayName").GetValue(x))

This returns the correct string, however i'm hardcoding the element and it just looks plain horrible. 

Apologises for this being vague and a particular awkward question to help with.

Comment: I am still waiting to see how the involved types are declared. If I could put these things into my Visual Studio, I could find a solution. Up to now it is just a guess. Please show us the declaration of the classes and structs involved. If the property is public, there is no need to use Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x.FieldValue` is an `object` you could try casting to check if it is of type `ObjectType.Extension`:

```cs
var test = scheduledTask.Fields.Select(x => {
   var asExtension = x.FieldValue as ObjectType.Extension;
   if(asExtension != null) return asExtension.DisplayName;
   else return x.FieldValue;
});
```

ETA: The `as` operator is a sort of safe-cast that will return null if the runtime type of LHS argument doesn't match the static type identified by the RHS argument.